# Play sound file inline at URL

Tags: javascript, html, audio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Linking To a Song</h2>

<p><a href="horse.mp3">Click here to play the sound</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am wondering how I can have the above link; CLICK > and play the sound file **inline** without opening a new window and displaying the ugly quicktime loader. I am hoping to use new HTML5 techniques with audio to simply allow 'Click > Play'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="new Audio('horse.mp3').play()">Click here to play the sound</a></p>
```

Of course, inline attributes are discouraged - you can do the same thing in a JavaScript file if you prefer.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's not working in  Firefox 25.0. But it works in Chrome. Alright, I'll give you the answer (for now)